# DNS magic to host multiple versions of the same site from nginx?

Tags: nginx, dns

I have three very-similar versions of a static website that I want to host (preferably) from the same nginx instance on the same VM.

Let's say my website's content is laid out like so:

```
/opt/mysite/
    flavor1/
        index.html
        ...all content for first flavor/version of the site
    flavor2/
        index.html
        ...all content for second flavor/version of the site
    flavor3/
        index.html
        ...all content for third flavor/version of the site
```

etc. Now let's pretend the VM has a public IP of `9000.1.2.3` (I know this is not valid IPv4 I'm just using this as an example). When I configure nginx like so:

```
http {
    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            root   /opt/mysite
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

...and then start nginx, I can go to `9000.1.2.3:8080` and see the default nginx welcome screen. So far, so good.

Now let's also pretend I have purchased three domain names: `example.com`, `example.net` and `example.info`. What I really want is this:

```
| Domain Name  |     Maps to     |   Which then serves   |
|--------------|:---------------:|:---------------------:|
| example.com  | 9000.1.2.3:8080 | /opt/mysite/flavor1/* |
| example.net  | 9000.1.2.3:9200 | /opt/mysite/flavor2/* |
| example.info | 9000.1.2.3:9300 | /opt/mysite/flavor3/* |
```

Meaning, if I go to, say, `http://example.com/fizz`, then ultimately, `9000.1.2.3/opt/mysite/flavor1/fizz` is what gets returned. But if I request `http://example.info/fizz`, then ultimately `9000.1.2.3/opt/mysite/flavor3/fizz` is what gets returned.

I personally don't care about what magic needs to be done to accomplish this: perhaps DNS configuration, nginx tuning, IP forwarding, etc. So I don't really care about the middle-column in my table above (the "*Maps to*" column). I just need a way for calls to these three domains to be served/backed by the same nginx instance running on a single VM, but serving different versions of the site for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a more complicated server to serve the files and the server could choose what flavor to use based on the hostname?

Comment: Thanks @matanso (+1) however I'd really like to keep it to nginx if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
server { 
    server_name example.com; 
    location / {
        root /var/flavor1;
    } 
} 
server {
    server_name example.net;
    location / { 
        root /var/flavor2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @matanso (+1) - I will give it a whirl! In the meantime, can I assume that I could just map all `A` records to the same `9000.1.2.3` IP without any other special configuration (at the DNS layer)? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I believe that what you're supposed to do.